# Accessing SalesForce products with PHP

Tags: php, salesforce

I'm having trouble finding documentation that makes me think that you can make requests with PHP to retrieve product listing from SalesForce. I see plenty of information about getting contacts, but not products. Is it possible to get products? If so, can you point to where I can learn about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to read the docs on the [Salesforce PHP Toolkit](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Force.com_Toolkit_for_PHP) and the [Salesforce WS API documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm).

Comment: I've looked at the toolkit and as far as I can see, there isn't a way to access the product info. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, to do that you just run a generic SOQL query against the Product2 and/or PriceBookEntry table. There are plenty of examples of how to do SOQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

All the objects in the following url can be accessed by the API. Search here for Product, you will see all the related info:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_list.htm

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve product listing from SalesForce

$queryString = 'SELECT Id, Name, ProductCode FROM Product2 ORDER BY Name LIMIT 10';
$products= $mySforceConnection -> query($queryString);
print_r($products);